# Is there no market feedback?

Tags: spiral-knights

I posted some energy/crown trade offers in the markets a few days ago, and now they just disappeared without any feedback.

I've read [on the wiki](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Energy_Depot#Market) that the offer expires in 10 days, and I've posted it just a few days ago, definitely less than 10.

So, is it normal to receive no feedback at all about the offer, or is there a bug somewhere and I might have actually lost the crowns or energy?

Comment: Are you sure that the trades didn't actually occur?

Comment: No, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: There is no notification when a sale is reached - your crowns/CE flash briefly, then update, but you don't get a message or an in-game letter or anything.

Comment: @Raven: post it as an answer then, please ^^ (I assume you mean there is no notification even if you are unlogged, *nor* a "console message" if you are, right?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spiral Knights will not go out of its way to notify you when someone accepts your offer to buy or sell Crystal Energy.

When a buyer is found, if you are online you will receive a console message, the relevant currency will flash once or twice, and then will update accordingly.

There is no in-game mail or to alert you that the transaction completed if you are offline when that happens - it sounds like it might be possible that the sale went through, and you were simply unaware that it completed successfully.

Comment: I've just noticed that if you are logged in, you'll also receive a console message.